# Is anyone else having problems launching UE4 4.23.1 on OS X 10.12?

Tags: unreal-4, macos

So I recently switched machines from Windows to OS X (I still have the Windows machine but it's not available to me sometimes so I wanted to keep going while it's processing some other stuff).
UE4 installs fine on my machine but I never actually get it to initialise the engine. Even if I start directly from the .uproject file it doesn't do anything.

Has anyone else had a similar experience and how did you solve the problem?

PS. I verified the 4.23.1 Version already so that's all good.

**Edit:**
I went to the engine directory and set all flags to 777. So permission is no longer an issue. Problem persists though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was solved by upgrading. For those who read this: If you're using the Wise Audio Engine (like I do) or any other third party application that you need for your Audio Workflow in UE4, please never upgrade to the latest OSX version straight away. In my case, upping the OSX to 10.13 did the job.